# Graph restrictions to reduce dataset in SPARQL

Tags: sparql

I am writing a SPARQL query for a dataset containing thousands of graphs, and I want to compute on the fly which graphs are to be included my search.  As an example, I might only want to include graphs written by me this year. This can be done easily enough by a restriction on the graph URI when the query is straightforward:

```
SELECT ?name WHERE {
  GRAPH ?g { [ foaf:name ?name ] }
  ?g dc:creator ex:me ; dc:created ?date
  FILTER( xsd:dateTime(?date) >= xsd:dateTime("2015-01-01") )
}
```

But suppose my query is more complex and I want a list of pairs of acquaintances.  The naïve implementation is something like this:

```
SELECT ?name WHERE {
  GRAPH ?g { ?name1 ^foaf:name/foaf:knows/foaf:name ?name2 }
  ?g dc:creator ex:me ; dc:created ?date
  FILTER( xsd:dateTime(?date) >= xsd:dateTime("2015-01-01") )
}
```

This works fine if all three FOAF triples are in the same graph.  But if any is in a different graph, it fails because `?g` binds to a single graph in each result.  I can explicitly write each of the three FOAF triples in their own `GRAPH` block, but then I have to associate each with their own graph URI variable, and repeat the graph restriction for each:

```
SELECT ?name WHERE {
  GRAPH ?g1 { ?p1 foaf:name ?name1 }
  ?g1 dc:creator ex:me ; dc:created ?date1
  FILTER( xsd:dateTime(?date1) >= xsd:dateTime("2015-01-01") )

  GRAPH ?g2 { ?p1 foaf:knows ?p2 }
  ?g2 dc:creator ex:me ; dc:created ?date2
  FILTER( xsd:dateTime(?date2) >= xsd:dateTime("2015-01-01") )

  GRAPH ?g3 { ?p2 foaf:name ?name2 }
  ?g3 dc:creator ex:me ; dc:created ?date3
  FILTER( xsd:dateTime(?date3) >= xsd:dateTime("2015-01-01") )
}
```

That code now does the right thing, but it rapidly becomes untenable as the query becomes more complex.  If the main query has *m* triples and the graph restriction has *n*, the complete query ends up with *m*×*n* triples.

Is there a better solution within standard SPARQL 1.1?  I'm aware that some SPARQL engines will fetch a graph from its URI, and then you can make that URI the URL of a GET request to a SPARQL endpoint, but that's not standard.  I had hoped the federated query mechanism might help, but it doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 1):

As I don't have your data at hand, I can't test my query reliably. However, you seem to need [subqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#subqueries).

> Subqueries are a way to embed SPARQL queries within other queries, normally to achieve results which cannot otherwise be achieved, such as limiting the number of results from some sub-expression within the query.

In your case, the objective is:

1. Getting the list of graphs for which you are the `dc:creator`
2. For each of those graphs, find some possibly useful triples

What you want as a result of your query isn't very clear, since you mention only `?name` after SELECT... although it's nowhere in the rest of the query. Here is how you could try using subqueries and maybe find inspiration to solve your problem:

```
SELECT ?name1 ?name2 WHERE {
  {GRAPH ?graph { ?p1 foaf:name ?name1 }}
  UNION {GRAPH ?graph { ?p1 foaf:knows ?p2 }}
  UNION {GRAPH ?graph { ?p2 foaf:name ?name2 }}
  { select ?graph where { #here we get the list of graphs you created
    ?graph dc:creator ex:me ; dc:created ?date
  FILTER( xsd:dateTime(?date) >= xsd:dateTime("2015-01-01") )
    }  
  }
}
```